# stm32 arm gcc compile with wrong libraries or specs

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32

When building from STM32CubeIDE, all good (obviously)
When building outside IDE, but using exactly the same toolchain (ST's) and the same compiler & link flags, I got some HardwareFault handler :((

So basically, some flags/specs are not good on my side.

Now after investigating a little (-verbose) I noticed there is a difference in IDE's toolchain libraries compared to mine (both at compile & link files)

This is a link example log

### IDE's

```
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.11.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.100.202210260954\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: mode armelf
                                                                                                                        
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.11.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.100.202210260954/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v6-m/nofp/crti.o succeeded
```

It is choosing
**../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v6-m/nofp/crti.o**

### Mine

```
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.11.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.100.202210260954\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: mode armelf
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.11.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm3
2.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.100.202210260954/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/nofp/crti.o succeeded
```

And mine is choosing
**thumb/nofp/crti.o**

For some reason, at my side appears that NANO is not choosen.
Moreover, libgcc is choosen in the first place!

### This is mine

```
./Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_ll_rcc.o
attempt to open ../../../test1\libgcc.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.11.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm3
2.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.100.202210260954/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/nofp\libgcc.a succeeded
```

### This is IDE's

```
./Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_ll_rcc.o
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.11.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.100.202210260954/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libc_nano.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.11.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.100.202210260954/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libc_nano.a succeeded
```

These are my link flags

```
`-O0`,
`-Wl,-verbose`,
`--specs=nosys.specs`,
`--specs=nano.specs`,
`-static`,
`-Xlinker --gc-sections`,
`-Xlinker --print-memory-usage`,
`-mfloat-abi=soft`,
`-mthumb`,
```

And these are IDE's

```
-mcpu=cortex-m0plus -T"STM32G0B1RETX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--verbose -static --specs=nano.specs -mfloat-abi=soft -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
```

What can be wrong?

Thanks in advace,

Comment: Embedded IDEs for Cortex M tend to prefer their own C runtime libs (CRT). These are not as standardized as ARM would like to think. If there's mismatching between the CRT and the linker script, then nothing will work. Additionally, Eclipse is a pox that the programming gods sent to punish mankind for thinking that free equals good. If you aren't constantly troubleshooting mysterious linker errors, then you aren't using Eclipse.

Comment: @Lundin I use Eclipse for years. No problems at all. It does exactly what the programmer wants. OP is simply forgotten the tell the compiler what is the target.

Comment: @orfruit you could save us from scrolling if you have removed the long path to the toolchain. Try to help us help you.

Comment: @0___________ Ok because I must have been using around 100 (no kidding) different programming IDEs over the past 20 years and if I'm to name the top 3 worst ones of all time, it's Simplicity Studio (Eclipse), Codewarrior (Eclipse) and LPCxpresso (Eclipse). The latter two hellspawns have now merged into a single hellspawn. They all stood out as extremely bad, slow and hopelessly broken. When working with STM32 I didn't even consider picking the Eclipse route of masochism, but went with Crossworks, which is commercial one. I use that for all Cortex M now regardless of silicon vendor.

Comment: Anyway, as the end of the rant, a half-decent IDE will pick things like `-mcpu=cortex-m0plus` as per default build settings when you create a new project for a specific target. If you have to dig them up and set them manually, then the IDE is bad. Always use IDEs that are aware of the specific target. Similarly, always pick a debugger which is aware of the existing peripherals and their registers on the specific target.

Comment: @Lundin If you fancy outdated, primitive IDE like Rowley (editor reminds me of the old ones from the 80s). Anyway, it is a personal preference. Your comments about peripherals, target settings etc. simply show that you have never used a decent version of Eclipse with decent plugins installed. Try for example STM one and then criticise.

Comment: @0___________ Eclipse is over 20 years old... There were no graphical IDEs in the 1980s...

Comment: @Lundin  *"there were no graphical IDEs in the 1980s..."* Did you hear about the company called Borland? *"Eclipse"* and in your opinion we use that 20y old  version.

Comment: @0___________ At least some 20-30 of the mentioned IDEs I've used were from Borland & post-Borland so yes... Turbo C from 1989 was not a graphical IDE, it was a pure text one designed for MS DOS. It has no resemblance what so ever to anything released in the Windows era.

Comment: @Lundin it was not graphical at all https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4qgs.png World is not PC centric

Comment: first step, always, after changing the tools or infrastructure is to disassemble and examine the binary, is the vector table in the right place, is it correct at least as far as reset goes, is it generating the proper instructions for the target archtecture?  dont care what chip you are developing for or what tools, that is step one.  have bricked and had to toss many a card when not doing this, many platforms today are more forgiving, but does not mean you skip these elementary steps.  esp with a hard fault on a cortex-m after a tool change is 99% of the time one thing.

Comment: when going your own and leaving the sandbox you need to start simple, and perhaps you did, backwards to a simple led blinker, no pll, no timers, no interrupts, count to n loop for timing, examine the disassembly of the binary carefully, etc.  also there is an expectation that when you leave the sandbox things wont work...and may never work, thus the sandbox.

Comment: turbo pascal and turbo c had ides, we didnt use that term then and they were graphical in the sense that they had menus and windows and all that albeit perhaps in a character mode.   and that was the end of my use of ides because they have been crap since the 80s, and continue to be horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have hoped this was obvious, but you need `-mcpu=cortex-m0plus` (or `-march=armv6-m`).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put as answer, thanks @Tom V for clue, you're the man :)

I just silly forgot to specify -mcpu=cortex-m0plus to my linker too!

And yes, I prefer VS Code as IDE and build externally with my own scripts. Just tired of ST's hidden params & updates that crashes old projects.

But I still have to use STM32Cube for debug on-target purposes, step into running code, view registers & peripheral definitions, etc.

Comment: Have you tried the Cortex Debug extension? It allowed me to abandon Eclipse completely!